# RRDtool cannot find in python

Tags: python, rrdtool

I have a remote server which have installed RHEL 5 and Python2.

```
OS Version:
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5 (Tikanga)

Python Version:
Python 2.4.3
```

I could find the rrdtool have installed on following path as well.

```
/usr/local/rrdtool/bin
```

But when I execute following command in a .py file I am getting an error.

```
import sys
import rrdtool
```

Error:

```
import rrdtool
ImportError: No module named rrdtool
```

Can someone explain why I am getting this error and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Python expects a python library. The directory `/usr/local/rrdtool/` contains the rrdtool binary, but not the bindings to use it in Python.

You need to install the matching python library, using pip for instance :

```
pip install python-rrdtool
```

Comment: I have used sudo yum install python-rrdtool instead of pip install. I am getting error: No Match for argument: python-rrdtool
Nothing to do

Comment: Yum is an utility for managing system packages, not python libraries. Probably there's no such `python-rrdtool` in yum packages list. Pip will look for python packages on a dedicated repository.

Comment: my remote server have not installed pip as well.